# Plotting of the sinosuidal functions according to the pixel in Python

Tags: python, function, matplotlib, pixel, matplotlib-animation

I want to plot two sinusoidal functions. The generation of the plotting should be done according to the pixel size, like pixel by pixel. Any help regarding how to do this? The code I used to generate the waveform[ image attached in below]is below:

```
%matplotlib notebook
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from IPython.display import HTML

amp = 0.5         # 1V        (Amplitude)
f = 20

frame_rate = 100
t = np.linspace(0, np.pi/2, 1000)
x = np.sin(t)
y = amp * (np.cos(2 * np.pi * f * t) + np.pi / 2)

# pixel size in inches (width,height)
dpi = 64
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 4), dpi=dpi)
line, = ax.step(x, y)

plt.show()

def animate(frame, x, y, line):
    line.set_data(x[:frame], y[:frame])
    y_new = 0.5 * (np.cos(2 * np.pi * 20 * t[:frame]/2) + np.pi / 2)
    line.set_ydata(y_new)
    return line,

interval = 1000 / frame_rate

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=1000, interval=interval, fargs=[x, y, line])

HTML(ani.to_jshtml())
```

I thought to use the OpenCV library for this purpose. Is there any other easier option?  Any help with codes, explanations and providing resources would be highly appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sld9F.png)

Comment: your question is quite unclear, can you please add code, an image of your desired results? It's not very clear how you want to _plot pixels_ with two sinusoidal functions as an  _image_

Comment: Thank you. Please look at my post now. I added code and what I want to see through the pixel grid.

Comment: Matplotlib is not the correct choice for pixel-perfect rendering; you'd probably be better off with just Pillow's pixel access.

Comment: I am looking for resources in terms of how to do it with suitable libraries. I used matplotlib for generation of the waveform. Now, I want to visualize the result according to the pixel grid.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a small example of how to plot a function with frame-varied parameters using Pillow, upscaling it 2x using nearest-neighbor interpolation so you can really see the pixels.

It saves the resulting animation as an animated GIF.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw


def func(phase):
    """
    Compute the x and y coordinates for the function points.

    Return two arrays, one for each dimension.
    """
    amp = 0.5
    f = 20

    t = np.linspace(0, np.pi / 2, 1000) + phase
    x = np.sin(t)
    y = amp * np.cos(2 * np.pi * f * t)
    return (x, y)


def rescale(arr, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max):
    """
    Rescale the values in arr from [in_min, in_max] to [out_min, out_max].
    """
    return (arr - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min


def main():
    images = []
    num_frames = 150
    for frame in range(num_frames):
        img = Image.new("RGB", (400, 200), (0, 0, 0))
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
        phase = frame / num_frames * 2 * np.pi
        xs, ys = func(phase)

        # convert xs/ys into pixel coordinates as [(x, y)] tuples
        coords = list(
            zip(
                rescale(xs, 0, 1, 0, img.width),
                rescale(ys, -1, 1, 0, img.height),
            )
        )

        draw.line(coords, fill=(255, 255, 255), width=1)

        img = img.resize((img.width * 2, img.height * 2), resample=Image.NEAREST)
        images.append(img)
    images[0].save(
        "so77844220.gif",
        save_all=True,
        append_images=images[1:],
        loop=0,
        duration=50,
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

For this code, the animation result (sans the upscaling to save SO's bandwidth) is:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the code. It works. However, I want to plot the functions in a pixel grid. The pixel value is 256*256. the rows and columns of the grid art should be 256 and 256 too. So that, the waveform generation would be done in the grid slowly. Is it possible?

Comment: In this example, the grid is `(400, 200)`; you can change that in the code.